# Angularjs get event when we click anywhere on page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing SPA using angularjs . I have one dropdown. If the user logs in then dropdown will be clickable and it expands various options like profile,logout etc. In app.js i have below code to expand dropdown

```
  if (cookieloginid != null) {
            var id = document.getElementById('ProfileDropdown');
    id.innerHTML = $scope.ProfileDropdown = '<div data-drop-down>' + ' <ul>' +
        '<li><a href="#/userProfile">User Profile</a></li>' +
        '<li>test1</li>' +
       ' <li onclick="logout(event)">logout</li>' +
    '</ul>'+'</div>'; 
        }
```

Above code works fine. If i click on dropdown that will expand and not close. After clicking on dropdown if i click anywhere on web page i want to close the expanded dropdown. May i know is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you try:
`angular.element('#ProfileDropdown').triggerHandler('Click')` on page load

Comment: You can use event.stopPropagation(); though it is not recommended

Comment: Thank you...... I am developing single page application. Where should i put above set of code?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by creating a custom directory for the above, see below link for the information:
http://www.competa.com/blog/an-angular-click-anywhere-to-close-dropdown-menu-directive/

or else you can add your custom event on document using jquery $(document) to perform the action.

See below links:
http://embed.plnkr.co/rpOgQC/

also you might want to use event.stopPropagation();, in case when you click on dropdown you might not end up in case where your drop down not getting opened.

Comment: Thank you. I can see dropDown directive in the plunker. So should i add one?

Comment: all i have confusion is i am using ui-routing. I have lot of ui-views. Where should i write directives?

Comment: make it global so, that you can reuse it.

Comment: Thanks. In my case no need to include clickCapture directive right?

Comment: No. you don't need that. It just for your understanding

Comment: Okay. I have added data-drop-down. i posted above code. But nothing happening. Am i missing anything?

Comment: did your directive getting called ?

Comment: No. I tested by adding debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149225/discussion-between-sumit-chauhan-and-niranjan-godbole).